# Is there a way to set an iOS app to automatically download data every night?

Tags: ios

We have a customer who wants us to have our iOS app check for new data posted every night and download it if it is available. As far as I can tell this is only possible if the app is already open or if they have someone physically accept a notification or initiate the process themselves.

Is this correct? I can't imagine Apple wanting to allow launching of an app and downloading data with no user interaction at all.

Comment: Have you googled on the subject? There is a thing called `Background Fetch` since iOS 7 avaiable - check this article by objc.io http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html - it basically wakes your up at specified intervals giving it 30 seconds to perform some tasks.

Comment: Yes, I have googled the subject. Background Fetch is great for tasks that take less than 30 seconds but I need to be able to download hundreds of MBs. Thanks. @Losiowaty

Comment: That's kind of relevant - why didn't you mention it in the question? :) IMHO downloading a lot of data without user knowledge sounds like a bad idea generally - can't you just download part of the data (i.e. article headers) and then only fetch specifics (i.e. articles) when user requests it?

Comment: I understand it's a bad idea generally but the customer needs the data to be available immediately when they aren't able to download the data because of outages. They're very much from a Windows world wanting the same features/functionality on iOS...

Comment: why do you need a nightly download? Just do a check when the user opens the app.

Comment: @rmaddy The user may not be able to connect to a wifi/cellular networks when they open the app in the case of a power outage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, generally you can only download data at exactly specified times if the app is actually running in the foreground, that is correct. It wouldn't matter if the app was open already or the user opened it from a notification, the point is that user interaction is required. So, the client can't have exactly what they want.

Look at background downloading (fetch) from iOS7+ where you can register the app to perform background downloading in advance of usage. iOS is fully in control of this and it may choose to run the app and it may not. iOS will monitor when your app is usually used by a particular user and, if appropriate, it will allow the app to run in the background to do some downloading before the user is expected to use the app.

In particular you're looking at `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:` and setting the `UIBackgroundModes` key with to `fetch` in the Info.plist.

---

As an aside, here's an idea based on your expanded information:

1. Use `idleTimerDisabled` to prevent the app from sleeping during main usage and keep a track of the time
2. After the main usage period of the app is over, start your downloads
3. After the downloads are done allow the screen to sleep
4. On the next day, if a user opens the app, repeat

It isn't perfect, but it's an approximation

Comment: This needs clarification. By "already open" I think the OP means that the app is running in the foreground. Background Fetch is the right feature to point to, along with NSURLSession's background downloads. With these features, the OP should be able to accomplish most of any reasonable requirement for scheduled background downloads. I think you'd do well to remove the first line, or else to explain the cases where this strategy can fail.

Comment: Thanks @Caleb, I've expanded the first line to be more clear and explicit about the difference between the user interaction and the automatic cases, thanks.

Comment: The problem I have is getting the download started say in the middle of the night when no one is there with the iPad currently asleep. The notification will get there but there's no way to use that to open my app or kick off the download with no interaction right? The only thing I can think of is if sleep is disabled and the app is left in the foreground (keeping the display on all night, ugh).

Comment: Push notifications can trigger a little download, but from your other comment you want to download lots of data and you aren't going to find a solution for that. I also agree with @Losiowaty that you shouldn't do that size of operation without user knowledge. Have you considered that they may be on a 3G connection at the time?

Comment: @Wain In this specific instance the devices would be plugged in connected to a Wifi network every night when the data needs to be downloaded.

Comment: @Wain The user's company is actually responsible for the new data being posted so the updated data may not be available when the user uses the app the last time for the day.

Comment: Well that's probably the closest you will get, alternate is first thing when the app is opened each day